# Can I auto-rotate the screen 180°?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, screen, auto-rotation

Is there any way to make the Android 2.1 automatic screen rotation rotate all the way up to 180°, instead of just 90° either way? I would very much like to be able to use my phone upside down, because the audio jack is on top.

I've looked all over the web and the only advice I found was to install a custom rom (like Cyanogen,) but I haven't found any builds suitable for my Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: There are log of apps available now for auto rotate on play store and I don't think anyone is using 2.1 anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe Android 2.1 allows this. I've read that the latest release Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) will have this feature.

Sorry I couldn't find the post that mentioned it but here is the [API link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this functionality if you have a custom launcher, like LauncherPro.  Samsung's TouchWiz does not support the 180 degree rotation.  You also need Android 2.2+, however, which introduced the `getRotation()` API.